# UI thread can not start after IDE changed

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, intellij-idea, jframe

I changed my IDE from Eclipse to IntelliJ IDEA. The new one started complaining about my code.

```
public class Controller {
private OknoGlowne frame;
private MenuListener menuListen = new MenuListener(this);
private TabListener tabListener = new TabListener(this);

public OknoGlowne getFrame() {
    return frame;
}

public Controller(){
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                frame = new OknoGlowne();
                frame.setVisible(true);             //error
                frame.addMenuListener(menuListen);
                frame.addTabListener(tabListener);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

So I commented this line. And add new line to constructor of UI frame.

```
public OknoGlowne() {
    jPanel.setVisible(true);
}
```

App start but UI doesn't show any more. IDEA create frame in different way than Eclispe. I have to switch.

Main

```
public class Runner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Controller();
    }
}
```

Comment: What error are you seeing? What happens if you compile via the command line instead of from an IDE?

Comment: I dont have any errors from compiling or runnig. App start and close `Process finished with exit code 0`

Comment: I don't see a main method. Can you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't really have anything to do with your IDEs. I bet if you ran it 100 times in eclipse, or from the command line, you'd get different results depending on how busy your system is.

The reason you aren't seeing the JFrame pop up is because you're using **invokeLater()** instead of **invokeAndWait()**.

The invokeLater() method immediately returns, at which point you're in a race condition: will the event thread display the EDT first, or will the main thread exit first? If the main thread exits first, then your program will exit before any windows are shown.

To prevent this, you have to use invokeAndWait() instead of invokeLater().

Comment: @GarryMoveOut It's a threading issue. It has nothing to do with your IDE. The fact that eclipse looks like it behaves a certain way is a coincidence, or a result of eclipse using a different amount of CPU time than IntelliJ. Try running from the command line with nothing else running, then try running from the command line while making your system as busy as possible. Either way the solution is the same: use invokeAndWait() instead of invokeLater().

Comment: I change it and still window doesn't pop up. App start and close immediately ` Process finished with exit code 0`

Comment: @GarryMoveOut Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with your updated code. Make sure it includes everything, and edit your question to include it.